# Vectors operations in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

How subtract each element of row vector of size `1xN` from column vector `Mx1` 
without using loop in MatLab?

```
N = 1:100
M = ones(1000,1)
```

Comment: Take a look at `bsxfun`

Comment: What you ask is unclear ... can you precise the expected output ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as suggested by Daniel

```
out = bsxfun(@minus, N,M);
```

but it might be more obvious to use [**`meshgrid`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) or [**`ndgrid`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to get the matrix you want:

```
out = meshgrid(N-1,M);
```

These two functions internally use `repmat` which [**is slower than `bsxfun`**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/), so rather go for the first approach. And `bsxfun` is always the fastest solution anyway ;)

Comment: `bsxfun` for the win!

Comment: If the number of columns in vector and in Matrix are different bsxfun works all the way?...

For e.g In my setting i have
N=[12 33 2 45 8 1 67 5 58]

M is a Matrix of 100 rows and 4 columns

I need to subtract each element of N from each Matrix  value 

can i do this with bsxfun?

Thanks

Comment: @AndreaCiarmiello `bsxfun` works for `a = 1xN` and `b = Mx1` or `a = MxN` and `b = MxN`. What you want won't work, as it is unclear how the result should look like. You should post a new question with a minimal example and the desired output for a given input. There will be an efficient solution as well, but its a different question then. Please consider also accepting this answer, if it helped you for now.